# How can I make a Gerrit reminder bot?

Tags: gerrit

As I have code reviews open in 5-6 gerrit instances it can happen too often to forget to notify people to perform reviews on them and as anyone knows, a CR that gets old also gets obsolete and the effort invested in it is mostly lost.

I am planning to write a `gerrit-reminder-bot` which queries all gerrit servers for reviews opened by you, checks the age and the status (no votes and no negative votes) and sends an email to each reviewer.

Now the question is if we already have something similar that can be improved or used as a starting point.

Please note that using gerrit event stream is useless in this case because we do want to send reminder notification for stalled reviews, and obviously that a stalled review does not get any notifications.

Answer (score 2):

We went with an "in-house" solution -
a script that runs a Gerrit-query and parses the (JSON) results.

**Basic flow**

1. Define: *How old is "old"* (in terms of "last modified" time),
   before you start nagging people
2. Get a list of all open Gerrit-changes - in our case - as a JSON:
   `ssh -p $gerritPort $gerritHost gerrit query --format=JSON --current-patch-set limit:$queryLimit status:open`
   note -

   - Each line of the result is a "mini-JSON" that should be parsed on its own
   - The summary-line has a different format - can ignore it completely
3. For each line

   - Parse the JSON to get the key/value pairs
   - If not "old enough" - skip it
   - `if (Verify < +1)` --> "Forgot to Fix the Build"
   - `else-if (CodeReview < +2)` --> "Forgot to Get a Good Review"
   - `else-if (CodeReview == +2 and Verify == +1)` --> "Forgot to Submit"

For each scenario we send a slightly different mail that describes the case,
with a link to the relevant Gerrit-change.
The mail is sent both to the owner and to the reviewers (in CC),
to cover cases where the owner is on vacation (or left).

Comment: Anything to share? Time to create a gerrit-facilitator-bot :)

Comment: (Have added the blueprint)